# Why this answer is not working, just for one test case?

Tags: optimization, error-correction

QUESTION LINK:https://codeforces.com/contest/1551/problem/A
SOLUTION:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long double  ll;
void solve(){
  long int n;
  cin>>n;
  long int d=n/3;
  n=n-d;
  ll s= ll (n)/2;
  cout<<round(s)<<" "<<d;
  cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
  long t;
  cin>>t;
    while(t--){
    solve();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Its working for all other test cases but not for 10^9 why so?

Answer (score 0):

> Its working for all other test cases but not for 10^9 why so?

It's not working for a lot of test cases, namely for all cases where the first number is printed in exponent (scientific) notation and for all cases where **n** is one less than a multiple of 3, where c<sub>1</sub> comes out 1 to high and c<sub>2</sub> 1 too low. The first defect can be repaired by casting the result of `round` to `long`, the second by correcting your computation for `(n%3==2)`.